# coverting strings to tuple in python3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

But now I wish to convert it to the following tuple format:

```
((1231, 123), (2341, 1210), (342,12), (5462, 565))
```

I really need to find a way to convert this data to the format directly above. I would greatly appreciate any help!

How to covert a string into pairs of tuple? I have already tried this

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f] 
    mylist = [mylist[x:x+1] for x in range(0, len(mylist), 3)]
    print(mylist)


data = ['I went to work but got delayed at other work and got stuck in a traffic and I went to drink some coffee but got no money and asked for money']
```

I want my output to be in this format

```
[('i', 'went'),('to', 'work'),('but', 'got').........]
```

I have tried this but not working

---

```
import itertools
import nltk
import collections
f=open('readme.txt','r')
data=f.read()
print(data)
d1 = data[0].split() 
output = list(itertools.zip_longest(d1[::2],d1[1::2],fillvalue = None)) 
print(output)
```

Edited from comment - File content:

```
['भिन्केन NNP डच NNP प्रकाशन NN समूह NN एल्सेभियर NNP एन.भी. FB को PKO अध्यक्ष NN हुनुहुन्छ VBF । YF कन्सोलिडेटिड NNP गोल्ड NN फिल्ड्स NN पीएलसी NNP का PKO पूर्व JJ सभापति NN ५५ CD वर्षीय JJ रूडोल्फ NNP अग्न्यु NNP लाई PLAI यस DUM ब्रिटिस NNP औद्योगिक JJ समूह NN को PKO सल्लाहकार NN को PKO रूप NN मा POP मनोनयन NN गरिएको VBKO थियो VBX । YF एकताका RBO केन्ट NNP चुरोट NN को PKO फिल्टर NN बनाउन VBI प्रयोग NN भएको VBKO एक CD प्रकार NN को PKO अस्बेस्टोस NNP ']
```

Comment: What if there is an odd number of words in the string? And why is `data` a list?

Comment: dont use `list` (or any other builtin name) as variable name, it hides it and you get problems later. Format your code: Copy&Paste it into your question, mark it , hit the **{}** to format it as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)
 wich also works for zipping unevenly lengthy list by supplying a default value (of None if not otherwise specified) to the shorter lists:

You split data at spaces and feed a sublists to zip : once starting at 0 and once starting at 1, both using every other (2nd) element only:

```
data = ['I went to work but got delayed at other work and got stuck in a traffic and I went to drink some coffee but got no money and asked for money']

import itertools
d1 = data[0].split() 

# use 2 partial lists, using every 2nd word, once staring at 0, once at 1
# you can change   fillvalue=None   to some other value or remove it - None is the default.
output = list(itertools.zip_longest(d1[::2],d1[1::2], fillvalue = None)) 

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[('I', 'went'), ('to', 'work'), ('but', 'got'), ('delayed', 'at'), ('other', 'work'), 
 ('and', 'got'), ('stuck', 'in'), ('a', 'traffic'), ('and', 'I'), ('went', 'to'), 
 ('drink', 'some'), ('coffee', 'but'), ('got', 'no'), ('money', 'and'), 
 ('asked', 'for'), ('money', None)]
```

---

The sublists fed to `zip_longest` look like:

```
print(d1[::2])

['I', 'to', 'but', 'delayed', 'other', 'and', 'stuck', 'a', 'and', 'went', 'drink', 
 'coffee', 'got', 'money', 'asked', 'money']
```

and

```
print(d1[1::2])

['went', 'work', 'got', 'at', 'work', 'got', 'in', 'traffic', 'I', 'to', 'some', 
 'but', 'no', 'and', 'for']
```

---

The following part is adapted from [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import ast

# create your file as utf8
with open("myfile.txt","w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    f.write("['भिन्केन NNP डच NNP प्रकाशन NN समूह NN एल्सेभियर NNP एन.भी. FB को PKO अध्यक्ष NN हुनुहुन्छ VBF । YF कन्सोलिडेटिड NNP गोल्ड NN फिल्ड्स NN पीएलसी NNP का PKO पूर्व JJ सभापति NN ५५ CD वर्षीय JJ रूडोल्फ NNP अग्न्यु NNP लाई PLAI यस DUM ब्रिटिस NNP औद्योगिक JJ समूह NN को PKO सल्लाहकार NN को PKO रूप NN मा POP मनोनयन NN गरिएको VBKO थियो VBX । YF एकताका RBO केन्ट NNP चुरोट NN को PKO फिल्टर NN बनाउन VBI प्रयोग NN भएको VBKO एक CD प्रकार NN को PKO अस्बेस्टोस NNP ']")

# load your file, using utf8
with open("myfile.txt","r",encoding="utf8") as f:
    data = f.read()
# convert the loaded string literal into a python list    
dataAsList = ast.literal_eval(data)

print(dataAsList)
print(type(dataAsList))

import itertools
d1 = dataAsList[0].split() 

# use 2 partial lists, using every 2nd word, once staring at 0, once at 1
# you can change   fillvalue=None   to some other value or remove it - None is the default.
output = list(itertools.zip_longest(d1[::2],d1[1::2], fillvalue = None)) 

print(p)
```

Output:

```
['भिन्केन NNP डच NNP प्रकाशन NN समूह NN एल्सेभियर NNP एन.भी. FB को PKO अध्यक्ष NN हुनुहुन्छ VBF । YF कन्सोलिडेटिड NNP गोल्ड NN फिल्ड्स NN पीएलसी NNP का PKO पूर्व JJ सभापति NN ५५ CD वर्षीय JJ रूडोल्फ NNP अग्न्यु NNP लाई PLAI यस DUM ब्रिटिस NNP औद्योगिक JJ समूह NN को PKO सल्लाहकार NN को PKO रूप NN मा POP मनोनयन NN गरिएको VBKO थियो VBX । YF एकताका RBO केन्ट NNP चुरोट NN को PKO फिल्टर NN बनाउन VBI प्रयोग NN भएको VBKO एक CD प्रकार NN को PKO अस्बेस्टोस NNP ']

<class 'list'>

[('भिन्केन', 'NNP'), ('डच', 'NNP'), ('प्रकाशन', 'NN'), ('समूह', 'NN'), 
 ('एल्सेभियर', 'NNP'), ('एन.भी.', 'FB'), ('को', 'PKO'), ('अध्यक्ष', 'NN'), 
 ('हुनुहुन्छ', 'VBF'), ('।', 'YF'), ('कन्सोलिडेटिड', 'NNP'), ('गोल्ड', 'NN'), 
 ('फिल्ड्स', 'NN'), ('पीएलसी', 'NNP'), ('का', 'PKO'), ('पूर्व', 'JJ'), 
 ('सभापति', 'NN'), ('५५', 'CD'), ('वर्षीय', 'JJ'), ('रूडोल्फ', 'NNP'), 
 ('अग्न्यु', 'NNP'), ('लाई', 'PLAI'), ('यस', 'DUM'), ('ब्रिटिस', 'NNP'), 
 ('औद्योगिक', 'JJ'), ('समूह', 'NN'), ('को', 'PKO'), ('सल्लाहकार', 'NN'), 
 ('को', 'PKO'), ('रूप', 'NN'), ('मा', 'POP'), ('मनोनयन', 'NN'), 
 ('गरिएको', 'VBKO'), ('थियो', 'VBX'), ('।', 'YF'), ('एकताका', 'RBO'), 
 ('केन्ट', 'NNP'), ('चुरोट', 'NN'), ('को', 'PKO'), ('फिल्टर', 'NN'), 
 ('बनाउन', 'VBI'), ('प्रयोग', 'NN'), ('भएको', 'VBKO'), ('एक', 'CD'), 
 ('प्रकार', 'NN'), ('को', 'PKO'), ('अस्बेस्टोस', 'NNP')]
```

Comment: thank you so much but then i need to import data and obtain this output.   [('I', 'went'), ('to', 'work'), ('but', 'got'), ('delayed', 'at'), ('other', 'work'), 
 ('and', 'got'), ('stuck', 'in'), ('a', 'traffic'), ('and', 'I'), ('went', 'to'), 
 ('drink', 'some'), ('coffee', 'but'), ('got', 'no'), ('money', 'and'), 
 ('asked', 'for'), ('money', None)]         the above program is working for manually typing the data but not working for reading file can you suggest me?

Comment: @AsiisPradhan  - Edit your question and paste the "file" content, indent each line of the file by 4 to make it look like the original file -< the 'code' environment respects linebreaks.

Comment: I have edited my question can you suggest what went wrong?

Comment: @AsiisPradhan Open your _FILE_ in an editor. Copy& paste all the text of the file into your question. I need to see the files layout to help. You can use `varName = """<put your files content here>"""` - it is a multiline string

Comment: -Still not giving the desire output. I want my output in the following form **[('भिन्केन', 'NNP'),(' डच',' NNP'),(' प्रकाशन',' NN')]

Comment: -ok i will ask a new question

Comment: @AsiisPradhan  edited again - see last part - for me it works. If you create a new question, put in a link to this one so others can crossreference

Comment: I cant thank you enough..thank you so much, i really appreciate it.

Comment: --its only working for this inputs--f.write("['भिन्केन NNP डच NNP प्रकाशन NN समूह NN एल्सेभियर NNP एन.भी. FB को PKO अध्यक्ष NN हुनुहुन्छ VBF । YF कन्सोलिडेटिड NNP गोल्ड NN फिल्ड्स NN पीएलसी NNP का PKO पूर्व JJ सभापति NN ५५ CD वर्षीय JJ रूडोल्फ NNP अग्न्यु NNP लाई PLAI यस DUM ब्रिटिस NNP औद्योगिक JJ समूह NN को PKO सल्लाहकार NN को PKO रूप NN मा POP मनोनयन NN गरिएको VBKO थियो VBX । YF एकताका RBO केन्ट NNP चुरोट NN को PKO फिल्टर NN बनाउन VBI प्रयोग NN भएको VBKO एक CD प्रकार NN को PKO अस्बेस्टोस NNP ']")
            Its not working for the data in the file. How can i over come that?

Comment: @AsiisPradhan [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) - if you cant fix it yourself, create a new questions, link to this one, and add demo-data to your new question so SO has data to work on regarding your parsing problem.

Comment: I am trying but not getting the desire result. and i am not allowed to ask another question for another day or two.

Answer (score 0):

```
splittedData = data[0].split(' ')
counter = len(splittedData)
if counter%2 == 0:
  pass
else:
  counter += 1
output_list= []
for x in range(counter/2):
  output_list.append((splittedData[x], splittedData[x+1]))
```